# Java Script коды клавиш

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте возникла непонятная ошибка при использовании кода клавиш, дело в том что все действия кодов работают кроме клавиш от 0 до 9 (48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57), любая клавиша на которую я назначаю действие работает а эти нет.

```
    document.onkeypress = function (n) {
    n = n || window.event;
    // Рабатает
    if (n.keyCode === 13) {        
            document.onClick = new Function("dispWordList();"); 
            document.onClick(next);
    } 
    // Не работает!
    else if (n.keyCode === 48){
            document.onClick = new Function("dispWordList();"); 
            document.onClick(next);
    }
    // Отменяем действие браузера
    return false;
   }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Событие keypress работает только для символьных клавиш. Т.е. нажатие, например, на стрелки не придет в keypress, но придет в keydown и в keyup. Поэтому смена keypress на keyup решит вашу проблему. Более подробно про эти события можете почитать [здесь](https://learn.javascript.ru/keyboard-events)

Comment: Спасибо, помогло.